# What phrase would you use instead of "We'll see" in the sense of making a decision based on how the situation develops?

Tags: phrase-choice

Would you tell me what phrase you would use instead of *We'll see* in the sense of making a decision based on how the situation develops or other factors become known? For example:

> I'm not sure if our truck is big enough to handle the cargo, but you can give the load's measurements and **we'll see**.

Comment: "...and then I will have a better idea" [whether it is big enough]?

Comment: ‘We’ll cross that bridge when we get to it’ is also possible, but a bit overused.